# Display update issue in a NextJS/React app

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, flexbox

I am working on a simple testing app using NextJS/React, and I have a question at the end.

Below is the code:

The Board.tsx file content:

```
'use client'

import './Board.css';
import {useState} from 'react';


export default function Board({count}:{count:number}) {
  const [cellLights,setCellLights] = useState(Array.from({length:0},()=>
                                              Array.from({length:0},()=>false)));
  const refresh = () => {
    let tempLights:boolean[][] = cellLights;
    for (let idx=0; idx<tempLights.length; idx++) {
      for (let idix=0; idix<tempLights[idx].length; idix++) {
        tempLights[idx][idix] = false;
      }
    }
    setCellLights(tempLights)
  } /* End of refresh */


  let rows:number[] = [];
  while (rows.length<count) {rows.push(rows.length)}

  let tempLights:boolean[][] = [];
  rows.forEach(rowElt => {
    let rowLights:boolean[] = [];
    rows.forEach(colElt => {
      rowLights.push(false)
    });
    tempLights.push(rowLights)
  });

  if (tempLights.length!=cellLights.length) setCellLights(tempLights)

  return <div className="board">
    {
      rows.map(item => (
        <div key={item}>
          <Row count={count}
               flags={cellLights[item]}
               cleanFn={refresh}/>
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
} /* End of Board */


function Row({count,flags,cleanFn}:{count:number,flags:boolean[],cleanFn:()=>void}) {
  let cells:number[] = [];
  while (cells.length<count) {cells.push(cells.length)}
    return <div className="row">
  {
    cells.map(item => (
      <div key={item}>
        <Cell flag={flags[item]}
              cleanFn={cleanFn}/>
      </div>
    ))
  }
</div>
} /* End of Row */


function Cell({flag,cleanFn}:{flag:boolean,cleanFn:()=>void}) {
    const [high, setHighFlag] = useState(flag);

  function cellClick() {
    cleanFn();
    setHighFlag(!high)
  }

return <>
    {(!high) && <div className="cell" onClick={cellClick}/>}
    {(high) && <div className="cell high" onClick={cellClick}/>}
  </>
} /* End of Cell */
```

And the Board.css file content:

```
.cell {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  margin:0.1rem;
}

.high {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

At the top is the app/page.tsx file:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Board from './components/Board'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
    {/* // <main> */}
      X4C APP
      <Board count={3}/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Here is what appears in the web browser when running the app, after clicking two square cells:

[image]

Now comes my question. One can see two cells highlighted in red. But this is not what I expect from my code.

Since when a click is performed, a call to *cleanFn()* -consequently to *refresh()*- is made, I would expect the previously highlighted cell to come back to its original color (yellow) before the last clicked cell becomes red.

Seeing the screenshot, this is obviously not what happens. Can anyone see where the flaw is in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is too much duplication of the `cellLights` array data. In fact, the code is recomputing the array data and passing extra data down as props. The issue is that the `Cell` component doesn't reset its state when the `Board` component's `cellLights` state updates.

Update the code so the `cellLights` is the single source of truth for which cell is highlighted.

Board

```
function Board({ count }: { count: number }) {
  // Initialize to count x count board
  const [cellLights, setCellLights] = useState(
    Array.from({ length: count }, () =>
      Array.from({ length: count }, () => false)
    )
  );

  const toggleCell = (row: number, col: number) => {
    // Reset board, toggle specific cell true
    setCellLights(
      Array.from({ length: count }, (_, r) =>
        Array.from({ length: count }, (_, c) => row === r && col === c)
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="board">
      {cellLights.map((flags, row) => (
        <div key={row}>
          <Row row={row} flags={flags} toggleCell={toggleCell} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Row

```
function Row({
  flags,
  toggleCell,
  row
}: {
  row: number;
  flags: boolean[];
  toggleCell: (row: number, col: number) => void;
}) {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      {flags.map((flag, col) => (
        <div key={col}>
          <Cell flag={flag} toggleCell={toggleCell.bind(null, row, col)} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cell

```
function Cell({ flag, toggleCell }: { flag: boolean; toggleCell: () => void }) {
  return <div className={flag ? "cell high" : "cell"} onClick={toggleCell} />;
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit display-update-issue-in-a-nextjs-react-app]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Drew_Reese. In the code "toggleCell.bind(null, row, col)", it is not clear to me how the first parameter (null) is handled. I have looked at some documentation about bind but at this point without full satisfaction. It looks like it could just be missing.

Comment: @Michel The first arg to `.bind` is the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#thisarg) arg that you could bind to the function. React function components are "instancesless" so their `this` is simply undefined. We pass null to "skip" the first arg so we can really pass the additional args which are what we want to pass to the function when it is invoked as the click handler when clicked. It's also common to use an anonymous function, e.g. `toggleCell={() => toggleCell(row, col)}`. Basically use what you prefer or is easier.